# How to override methods of a class (without interface implementation) I received in reflection:

Tags: java, android, reflection, overriding, webviewclient

I'm writing an SDK. In some logic of this SDK I need to recognize a `WebView` on screen attach a `WebViewClient` to it and use its methods like so:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
     if(!loadingFinished) {
       redirect = true;
     }
     if(isCaptureMode()) {
       wv.setAlpha(0.1f);
     }

     loadingFinished = false;
     view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
         return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
    loadingFinished = false;
    ABLogger.d("onWebViewDetected() onPageStarted");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      if (!redirect) {
          loadingFinished = true;
      }

      if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
         ABLogger.d("onWebViewDetected() onPageFinished");
                        onWebViewLoaded(view, true);
       } else {
           redirect = false;
       }
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       ABLogger.e("Failed to load site with url '%s'. error: %s", view.getUrl(), error.getDescription());
    } else {
      ABLogger.e("Failed to load site with url '%s'. error: %s", view.getUrl(), error.toString());
    }
    onWebViewLoaded(view, false);
  }
});
```

And this works well, In some other cases I'm dealing with **Cordova** apps in which case I receiving a `SystemWebView` view instead of `WebView` view. In this case the `SystemWebView` expects to get a `SystemWebViewClient` class in the `setWebViewClient` method. Now I don't have the **Cordova** class in my SDK. So I'm doing it all using reflection:

```
private Class getCordovaSystemWebViewClient() {
    if (mSystemWebViewClient == null) {
        try {
            this.mSystemWebViewClient = Class.forName(MapperBase.KEY_VIEW_CORDOVA_SYSTEM_WEB_VIEW_CLIENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return mSystemWebViewClient;
}
....

Class classCordovaSystemWebViewClient = getCordovaSystemWebViewClient();
Constructor constructor = classCordovaSystemWebViewClient.getConstructors()[0];
Object webViewClient = null;
Object o = constructor.newInstance(null);
```

**The Question:** Now that I have the `SystemWebViewClient` class instance, how can I override its methods? as I do with the regular `WebViewClient`?

Is there a way to do something like:

```
Object o = constructor.newInstance(null) {
    //provide an implementation for cetain methods.
};
```

Or just replace the implementation of some of the methods in the class?

Comment: Not sure it would help but this sounds like a `Proxy` would be useful. See [JavaSpecialists - Dynamic Proxies - Short Tutorial](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue005.html) for a usage.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, you would be right if WebViewClient implemented some kind of interface, but it doesn't: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java
So I don't think I can use the 'Proxy' in this case